# Background images using Breakpoints and Picture

Tags: 7, media

I want to serve my background images by breakpoints.  I can't seem to find an out of the box way to do this using the Breakpoints and Picture modules, which I'm using for some node images.

Has anyone implemented this using Picture/Breakpoints?

Comment: What do you mean by "serve images by breakpoints"?

Comment: And is there any theme you use like Omega or Zen? Please explain better what you try to do and what you have so far.

Comment: I'm using Omega 3.  Currently I use a background image for the front page, and they are high def images.  So, I want to use a version of the image according to the size of the browser display.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use [Group Background Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_background_image) with the patch that you can get [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_background_image/issues/2502001#comment-12602278). This allows background images, through the integration of the Picture and Breakpoints modules. The configuration is super easy, and you can change existing div field groups into background images in a split second.